# Multitasking Camera Access Entitlement took very long times to response

Tags: ios, camera

I am developing chat/video call app, then I want to camera continue to running when app in background.

Then I send request to get ***Multitasking Camera Access Entitlement***

After request, i got the mail response:

```
Dear Developer,

Your request to use the Multitasking Camera Access Entitlement has been received. We'll review your information and contact you soon with a status update.

Best regards,
Multitasking Camera Access Requests Team
```

But I never get the accepted, even I request 3 times, first times from 1 years ago.

Does someone meet same problem?

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow. You are free to waste your rep on a bounty but that won't protect the question from being closed when the bounty expires.

Comment: There is a way to communicate with your reviewer at Apple. Stack Overflow isn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to a minimum deployment target of iOS 16 should get around the problem.  That is because the requirements have been removed according to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/accessing_the_camera_while_multitasking

The documentation is not completely accurate because it only works for iPads with Stage Manager available.

Here is an example app:

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

/// Camera Permission Check
/// Requires iPad with Stage Manager Support
/// e.g. iPad Pro (11-inch) 4th generation with iOS 16.1
///
/// Containing app must have iOS deployment target 16.0
class CameraPermissionCheck {
    
    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    init() {
        // Configure the capture session.
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        if captureSession.isMultitaskingCameraAccessSupported {
            // Enable using the camera in multitasking modes.
            captureSession.isMultitaskingCameraAccessEnabled = true
            print("MultiTasking Camera Access Enabled")
        }
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        // Start the capture session.
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }
}
```

It will print out `MultiTasking Camera Access Enabled` to the console.

Comment: Hey, Can we use this without an entitlement for iOS 16 (and up) apps? The documentation is confusing. I'm always getting isMultitaskingCameraAccessSupported false for iPhone 12 pro.

Comment: I think it wouldn't work because its the multi-tasking aspect that it is about, and that would mean iPad not iPhone.

Comment: Ok. I have added the entitlement plist now. Can you please let me know how to add that entitlement to the app identifier in the developer console? Because I don't see any option to enable that there (Only see capabilities and services).

Comment: I haven't done the procedure, but to get it going you use https://developer.apple.com/contact/request/multitasking-camera-access/

Comment: The link doesn't work as it returns an unauthorized error (I have app manager access to the dev console and signed in without any issue)

Comment: Worked for me but I have full privileges on the app team.