How to use Camera Multitasking in development mode
According to the official documentation, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_avfoundation_multitasking-camera-access

Before submitting an app with this entitlement to the App Store, you
need permission to use the entitlement.

What if I need to use this entitlement for development purpose only ?
com.apple.developer.avfoundation.multitasking-camera-access 

Is it possible to use it ? I can't find an official statement saying that it is not possible even for just development.
If it is possible, how to do that ? (assuming the device is iPhone, not iPad)

I have not gone through, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74977449/833395 might help
